# MySQL keeps stopping

Tags: mysql, rackspace

Came into work this morning to find one of our servers had mysql not running. Checking logs, I found a empty log file for today. It has been created around 530am, the Rackspace server panel says the server was "Last Updated:" around the same time. I rebooted the box to try and see if mysql was just not starting on boot, and it start.. I also ran "sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults" and found it was already in the list. One of the other developers in the office told me this was the 3 time in the last 2 week that the box has turned off mysql without errors or warnings. New Relic shows the server has not gotten over 60% of memory, so I have no idea why it keeps turning off.. Any ideas?

I have removed sudo and changed root passwords just incase someone in the office was turning it of unintentionally or something stupid like that.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support. Try the DBA and/or serverfault sites.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/